# Absolute Positioned DIV within another Absolute positioned DIV does not show on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, html

Please refer to http://stonepay.sonikastudios.com/css/style.css as well as http://stonepay.sonikastudios.com/ for the actual page reference if you like.

I have a dropdown menu that shows up on click. This works on the "Our Services" and "Our Projects" menu items, and the fade-in and all works just fine. Being dropdown menus that cannot impede with other layout elements, the div.submenu elements are all set to position:absolute; (and of course, the parent div is set to position:relative; so it's not absolute to the page, but rather, to the menubar itself).

The div.submenu_close elements are nested at the end of each div.submenu intsance. It is also set to position:absolute;

To summarize, here's my CSS:

```
.submenu {
    position:absolute;
    width:auto;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 10px!important;
    background-image:url('/images/submenu_bg.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    z-index:99;
    background-color:#262626;
    display:none;
}

.submenu_column {
    margin-top:10px !important;
    margin-bottom:10px !important;
}

.submenu_close {
    width:11px !important;
    height:11px !important;
    background-image:url("/images/submenu_close.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:7px;
    right:7px;
    z-index:15 !important;
    border:1px solid #f00;
    display:block;
}
```

And the HTML structure is liek this (simplified to emphasize only structure):

```
<div id="menubar">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li class="current originalcurrent"><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about-us.php">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="/our-services.php" id="services_menu" class="topmenu">OUR SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="/our-projects.php" id="projects_menu" class="topmenu">OUR PROJECTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="/financing-leasing.php">FINANCING &amp; LEASING</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact-us.php">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="submenu" id="services_submenu">
        <div class="grid_3 alpha omega right_dotted submenu_column">
        </div>
        <div class="grid_3 omega right_dotted submenu_column" style="width:175px;">
        </div>
        <div class="submenu_close"><a href="#"><img src="/images/blank.gif" width="100%" height="100%"></a></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="submenu" id="projects_submenu">
        <div class="grid_3 alpha omega right_dotted submenu_column">
        </div>
        <div class="grid_3 omega right_dotted submenu_column" style="width:175px;">
        </div>
        <div class="submenu_close"><a href="#"><img src="/images/blank.gif" width="100%" height="100%"></a></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This makes my .submenu_close divs appear just fine on the bottom right corner just fine.. EXCEPT on internet explorer (of course it's IE again).

As you can see I have the z-index elements set up just fine. When I change the display mode of the .submenu_close to float:left instead of position:absolute, it shows up just fine, so I know it's not a z-index issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Even though you have it as one of the tags, IE8 does not appear to render incorrectly. Are you sure that's one of the version where this problem occurs?

Comment: My mistake - I had my IE8 in IE7 mode. Yes, IE8 works fine. Still need it to work on IE7 though.

Comment: seems to work in IE8 in IE7 compatibility mode for me.

Comment: Just a note on the "click", most people would expect the menu on mouse over not on click.

Comment: Tried the hover - but since they want the fade, and the positioning of the submenu is absolute to the header div rather than each menu, it was a huge pain to do. So I switched to the click mechanism.. the menu's extensive enough I wouldn't want it to flicker on a random mouse movement. I might add a small downward arrow to indicate that the menu will fly-out on click perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to [**a known bug in IE7**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html) (see right side bar) regarding nested absolute, fixed, and relative divs.  The ordering you explained is not exactly as documented, but from my experience you need to avoid nesting divs with these attributes if you want it to work correctly across all versions of IE.

Comment: So you're saying i can't nest an absolute positioned div within another absolute positioned div?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is rather caused by the [IE6/7 broken stacking order](http://therealcrisp.xs4all.nl/meuk/IE-zindexbug.html) (also known as the z-index bug). What you need to fix it is to raise the z-index of your close button to more than its container.

Comment: Tried it - the .submenu z index is much lower than the .submenu_close z-index. Still does not show.

Comment: I tried everything.. even z-index: 25 !important; typeof syntaxes to override it. Nothing.. by removing the background from the containing .submenu div, I confirmed that the .submenu_close div is located in the right position - just hides behind the .submenu div which has a lower z-index still...

Comment: Are you sure? Because when I look now, the close button is there and completely visible.

Comment: I fixed it using a completely different methodology... I couldn't get a clear fix here.